# Get datas contained in a dynamic json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i can't get dynamic datas that are contained into an array, here the array

```
  [addresses] => Array
        (
            [DYNAMIC-ADDRESS] => -249310
        )
```

I'am tryng to get the  DYNAMIC-ADDRESS, or rather the text contained on the ['...'] (In this case the text is DYNAMIC-ADDRESS) for get the balance, and for do a check on my database, i have already tried

```
$ReceiveAddress=$DATA['addresses']['0'];
```

And then for get the balance

```
$ReceiveAddress=$DATA['addresses']["$ReceiveBitcoinAddress"];
```

But this doesn't work...

Comment: oK GOOD SYNTAX IS $ReceiveAddress=key($DATA['addresses']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is the only key-value pair in the array, you can use `key`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

```
$dynamic_address = key($array);
$value = $array[$dynamic_address];
```

In case you're handling an array with several elements, Consider using `foreach` loop.

> [addresses] => Array
>           (
>               [DYNAMIC-ADDRESS] => -249310
>           )

```
foreach($addresses as $param => $value){
   //$param would be DYNAMIC-ADDRESS in a specific "round"
   //$value would be -249310
}
```

I would consider to change the format of the returned data's array, unless its a 3rd party API - there's no reason you should work with unknown key's names.